# One parameter doesn't save in access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have tried but can't find the error, I also tried the debugging mode. It seems that I'm missing very obvious here.

Problem: One of my parameter doesn't save which is `SmsMessage` but others are saving. Please check my code/Method.

```
Private Sub saveData(ByVal strIndex As String, ByVal strFrom As String, ByVal strMessage As String, ByVal strDateTime As String)  
    Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO tblTempMessageLog([SmsIndex], [SmsSender], [SmsMessage], [SmsTimeDate]) VALUES(@SI,@SS,@SM,@SDT)"
    conn.Close()
    conn.Open()
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
    With cmd.Parameters
        .AddWithValue("@SI", strIndex)
        .AddWithValue("@SS", strFrom)
        .AddWithValue("@SM", strMessage)
        .AddWithValue("@SDT", strDateTime)
    End With
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()
```

Table:

[image]

Comment: Set a breakpoint and check that `strMessage` is not empty.  You should also save the date as `Date` not string if you want them to act like Dates lates

Comment: it's not empty. thats why ive been wondering why? it's ok because i will split that later on so my expected value there is date:time

Comment: Could you paste what the value is? And do you get an exception?

Comment: ID/RESULT/YearTaken(e.g. 2015001/RESULT/2015) that's my expected value. no the program runs fine, but when i check the database the message is empty.

Comment: That's the value for `strMessage`? Let's try a few things. Make the value for `strMessage = "Test"`, make sure it inserts. Next step, try removing the `/` from the string.Is it possible to change the format for `strMessage` if you needed to? (do you have to save it like that?)

Comment: i change the value of the strMessage and it work. but the problem here i cant change the format. is it possible to convert that to string? i have tried toString and still doesn't save.

Comment: I tried to insert "2015001/RESULT/2015" value to msaccess 2013 table and there is no problem. Are you sure it is the problem?
Can you also try to create a new table in msaccess "Table1" and a new field to it "field1" of type Long Text and then insert manually this value.

Comment: i have found the real problem. this the strMessage i'm recieving "" & vbCrLf & "20150007/SCORE/2015" & vbCrLf & "". i'm so dumb that i didn't see that. now i have to extract again.

Comment: Been there, done that! CR hides the data in whatever tool I was using to view the data - like a single line TextBox.